# CSS padding dissapears when submitting form

Tags: php, html, css

I have made a contact form using PhP, HTML and CSS. When I submit the form with incorrect information, the CSS padding dissapears. Do any one see what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
  $errors = array();

  $name       = $_POST['name'];
  $email      = $_POST['email'];
  $message    = $_POST['message'];

  if (empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Name, email and message are required!';
  } else {
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
      $errors[] = 'That\'s not a valid email address!';
    }
    if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
      $errors[] = 'Name must only contain letters!';
    }
  }

  if (empty($errors) === true) {
    mail('name@example.com', 'Contact form', $message, 'From: ' . $email);
    header('Location: index.php?sent');
    exit();
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A contact form</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/application.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    if (isset ($_GET['sent']) === true) {
      echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me!</p>';
    } else {
      if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($errors as $error) {
          echo '<li>', $error,'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul';
      }
      ?>
      <form action="" method="post" class="skinny_wrapper wrapper_padding">
        <p>
          <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" <?php if (isset($_POST['name']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['name']), '"'; } ?>>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" <?php if (isset($_POST['email']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['email']), '"'; } ?>>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
          <textarea name="message" id="message"><?php if (isset($_POST['message']) === true) { echo strip_tags($_POST['message']); } ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
        </p>
      </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Screenshots:**

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgnWH.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSx6p.png)

Comment: you didn't post any css

Comment: `echo '</ul';` this is the problem . It should be `echo '</ul>';`  And `echo '<li>', $error,'</li>';` need to be `echo '<li>'. $error .'</li>';`  Still after that code need lot of improvement

Comment: @Anant it's "typo day" so it seems.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  he is having the same issue on some other lines of his code as well. I am astonished  why don't he get any error

Comment: @Anant why astonished? they're not checking for errors ;-) so, no surprise there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Also may be this is the reason too :-  https://eval.in/734922

Comment: @Anant that too; it's failing them on too many levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably some css rules were overwriten by additional class which appears during validation.